# Geometry Question. How to do?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

In a space, $\Pi$ is a plane and $l$ is a straight line, and they intersect at the point $O$. Suppose $A$, $C$, $E$ are points on $\Pi$ while points $B$, $D$ are points on $l$, such that $AB$ and $CD$ are perpendicular to $l$, while $BC$ and $DE$ are perpendicular to $\Pi$. If $OA=72$, $OE=42$ and $AE=54$, find the length of $OC$.

Comment: I suspect your plane is not II (doubled capital 'i'), but rather it is Π (Greek capital 'pi').

Comment: Yes, it should be Π but not II.

Comment: @Ray: Would you please consider editing your title? As G. Sassatelli says, "Plane Geometry Question" is counter-descriptive (you're asking about a plane, but not about _plane geometry_, which is geometry _in a plane_), while "please help" adds no mathematical information, only an unseemly sense of desperation that (judging from discussions in comments and meta) makes people _less likely_ to help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Since $DE$ and $BC$ are orthogonal to plane $\Pi$, the points $E$ and $C$ are the orthogonal projections of points $D$ and $B$ respectively on the plane $\Pi$. Hence the line $CE$ is the orthogonal projection of $l$ and must pass through the point $O = l \cap \Pi$. Thus, the plane $\Pi^*$ spanned by $l$ and its orthogonal projection $CE$ is orthogonal to $\Pi$.

Let $M$ be the midpoint of segment $AO$. Since $AO = 72$ the two halves $AM = OM = 36$. Construct the sphere $s_M$ centered at point $M$ and of radius $36$. Then points $O$ and $A$ lie on the sphere $s_M$. Furthermore, let $k = s_M \cap \Pi^*$ be the circle formed by the intersection of the sphere $s_M$ with plane $\Pi^*$. Let $H$ be the second intersection point of circle $k$ with the line $CE$, the other one being $O$. Then, by construction $H$ is the orthogonal projection of point $A$ on $CE$, i.e. $\angle \, AHO = 90^{\circ}$ because, say $H \in k \subset s_M$ so $HM = AM = OM = 36$ which means that triangle $AHO$ is right-angled. Since the plane $\Pi$ passes through the center of the sphere $s_M$, its intersection line $OH$, which coincides with $CE$, passes through the center of the circle $k$, so $HO$ is a diameter of $k$.

By assumption, point $B \in l$ is such that $\angle \, ABD = 90^{\circ}$ so the triangle $ABO$ is right angled with $M$ midpoint of the hypotenuse $AO$. Therefore, $BM = AM = OM = 36$, so $B$ lies on the sphere $s_M$ and since it is on the plane $\Pi^*$, it must lie on the circle $k$. Consequently, triangle $HBO$ is right-angled with $\angle \, HBO = 90^{\circ}$. Furthermore, $BC$ is the altitude through $B$ of the triangle $HBO$ and since $D \in l$ and $CD \perp l$ by assumption, triangle $CDO$ is right-angled.

Now the calculations. Let $\angle \, AOE = \beta$. By the cosine formula in triangle $AEO$,
$$\cos(\beta) = \frac{AO^2 + EO^2 - AE^2}{2 \cdot AO \cdot EO} = \frac{72^2 + 42^2 - 54^2}{2 \cdot 72 \cdot 42} = \frac{2}{3}$$ Since triangle $AHO$ is right-angled, $$\frac{HO}{AO} = \cos(\beta) = \frac{2}{3}$$ so $$HO = \frac{2}{3} \, AO = \frac{2}{3} \, 72 = 48$$ Therefore, $HE = HO - EO = 48 - 42 = 6$. Denote by $x = CE$. Then $HC = HE - CE = 6 - x$ while $OC =  CE + EO = x + 42$. Now, in the right-angled triangles $HBO$ and $CDO$ the following identities hold:
$$BC^2 = HC \cdot OC = (6-x)(x+42) \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\,
DE^2 = CE \cdot OE = x \cdot 42 = 42 x$$ By the similarity of triangles  $DEO$ and $BCO$,
$$\frac{DE}{BC} = \frac{OE}{OC}$$ which when squared on both sides becomes
$$\frac{DE^2}{BC^2} = \frac{OE^2}{OC^2}$$ 
$$\frac{42x}{(6-x)(x+42)} = \frac{42^2}{(42+x)^2}$$
Cancel out the common terms
$$\frac{x}{6-x} = \frac{42}{42+x}$$ When you solve it, you get
$$x =  12 \sqrt{14} - 42$$ which means that 
$$OC = OE + EC = 42 +  12 \sqrt{14} - 42 = 12 \sqrt{14}$$

Comment: Is there any method using dot product in vector algebra which can solve this problem too?

Comment: Why by construction H is the orthogonal projection of point A on CE,since angle AHO is right angle by Thale's theorem?

Comment: Why HO is diameter of k? I don't understand. Could you explain please?

Comment: @RayCheng By construction, $H$ and $O$ are the intersection points of the line $CE$ with the sphere $s_M$. Therefore $HM = AM = OM$ so by Thale's theorem $\angle \, AHO = 90^{\circ}$. The sphere $s_M$ is centered at $M$ and the plane  $\Pi$ passes through the center $M$, so $\Pi$ is diameter plane.  $k = s_M \cap \Pi^*$ where $\Pi^* \perp \Pi$. The center $O_k$ of $k$ is on $\Pi^*$ and the line $MO_k \perp \Pi^*$. However, $\Pi^* \perp \Pi$ and $M \in \Pi$, so the whole line $MO_k \subset \Pi$. Therefore, $O_k \in \Pi \cap \Pi^{*} = OH$, i.e. $OH$ is the diameter of $k$.

Comment: @RayCheng Think of it like this: of you have a sphere, $s_M$, and you intersect it with a plane, $\Pi^*$, then the intersection is a circle. Then the center of the circle, which lies in the plane, $\Pi^*$, is the orthogonal projection of the center, $M$, of the sphere onto the plane. Hence the line connecting the center of the sphere to the center of the circle is orthogonal to the intersecting plane $\Pi^*$. Then a plane, in our case $\Pi$, through the center of the sphere, $M$, and orthogonal to the intersecting plane, $\Pi^*$, contains the line connecting the two centers.

Comment: @RayCheng Probably one can calculate it using vectors, but I personally like to use my geometric imagination and creativity because it saves me a lot of computational, unilluminating, boring work. And sometimes, to get the right hint which combination of vector equations to use, you anyway have to imagine the geometric situation. So often, I do not bother if I can avoid it all together. And by the way, when you solve the problem, it is much faster sometimes geometrically, but longer to write and describe the solution. That saves me a lot of